# how to force pymongo to reconnect if the connection is down , and do the operation?

Tags: python, pymongo

I am trying to figure out how to handle `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError` if the data is down or somehow connecting to studio 3T (mongogui) makes to down the database . so I want to reconect to mongo .

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)
    db = client.info_collect
    collection = db['info']
    if collection.count_documents({'link': url}) < 1:
        collection.insert_one(add_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should just wrap your code inside a try-except block where you handle the ServerSelectionTimeoutError exception by retrying to reconnect and execute the same query inside the except block again.
something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

try:
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)
    db = client.info_collect
    collection = db['info']
    if collection.count_documents({'link': url}) < 1:
        collection.insert_one(add_dict)

except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError as e:

    client = pymongo.MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)
    db = client.info_collect
    collection = db['info']
    if collection.count_documents({'link': url}) < 1:
        collection.insert_one(add_dict)
```